# Using Kafka Connect HOWTO "commit offsets" as soon as a "put" is completed in SinkTask

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, flush, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka Connect to get messages from a Kafka Broker (v0.10.2) and then sync it to a downstream service.

Currently, I have code in `SinkTask#put` that will process the `SinkRecord` & then persist it to the downstream service.

A couple of key requirements,

1. We need to make sure the messages are persisted to the downstream service AT LEAST once.
2. If the downstream service throws an error or says it didn't process the message then we need to make sure that the messages are re-read again.

So we thought we can rely on `SinkTask#flush` to effectively back out of committing offsets for that particular poll/cycle of received messages by throwing an exception or something that will tell Connect not to commit the offsets, but retry in the next poll.

But as we found out `flush` is actually time-based & is more or less independent of the polls & it will commit the offsets when it reaches a certain time threshold.

In 0.10.2 `SinkTask#preCommit` was introduced, so we thought we can use it for our purposes. But nowhere in the documentation it is mentioned that there is a 1:1 relationship between `SinkTask#put` & `SinkTask#preCommit`.

Since essentially we want to `commit offsets` as soon as a single `put succeeds`. And similarly, **not** commit the offsets, if that particular `put` failed.

How to accomplish this, if not via `SinkTask#preCommit`?

Answer (score 24):

Getting data into and out of Kafka correctly can be challenging, and Kafka Connect makes this easier since it uses best practices and hides many of the complexities. For sink connectors, Kafka Connect reads messages from a topic, sends them to your connector, and then periodically *commits* the largest offsets for the various topic partitions that have been read and processed.

Note that "sending them to your connector" corresponds to the `put(Collection<SinkRecord>)` method, and this may be called many times before Kafka Connect commits the offsets. You can control how frequently Kafka Connect commits offsets, but Kafka Connect ensures that it will only commit an offset for a message when that message was successfully processed by the connector.

When the connector is operating nominally, everything is great and your connector sees each message once, even when the offsets are committed periodically. However, should the connector fail, then when it restarts the connector will start at the *last committed offset*. That might mean your connector sees some of the same messages that it processed just before the crash. This usually is not a problem if you carefully write your connector to have *at least once* semantics.

Why does Kafka Connect commit offsets *periodically* rather than with every record? Because it saves a lot of work and doesn't really matter when things are going nominally. It's only when things go wrong that the offset lag matters. And even then, if you're having Kafka Connect handle offsets your connector needs to be ready to handle messages *at least once*. Exactly once is possible, but your connector has to do more work (see below).

**Writing Records**

You have a lot of flexibility in writing a connector, and that's good because a lot will depend on the capabilities of the external system to which it's writing. Let's look at different ways of implementing `put` and `flush`.

If the system supports transactions or can handle a batch of updates, your connector's `put(Collection<SinkRecord>)` could write all of the records in that collection using a single transaction / batch, retrying as many times as needed until the transaction / batch completes or before finally throwing an error. In this case, `put` does all the work and will either succeed or will fail. If it succeeds, then Kafka Connect knows all of the records were handled properly and can thus (at some point) commit the offsets. If your `put` call fails, then Kafka Connect assumes doesn't know whether any of the records were processed, so it doesn't update its offsets and it stops your connector. Your connector's `flush(...)` would need to do nothing, since Kafka Connect is handling all the offsets.

If the system doesn't support transactions and instead you can only submit items *one at a time*, you might have have your connector's `put(Collection<SinkRecord>)` attempt to write out each record individually, blocking until it succeeds and retrying each as needed before throwing an error. Again, `put` does all the work, and the `flush` method might not need to do anything.

So far, my examples do all the work in `put`. You always have the option of having `put` simply buffer the records and to instead do all the work of *writing to the external service* in `flush` or `preCommit`. One reason you might do this is so that you're writes are time-based just like `flush` and `preCommit`. If you don't want your writes to be time-based, you probably don't want to do the writes in `flush` or `preCommit`.

**To Record Offsets or Not To Record**

As mentioned above, by default Kafka Connect will periodically record the offsets so that upon restart the connector can begin where it last left off.

However, sometimes it is desirable for a connector to record the offsets *in the external system*, especially when that can be done atomically. When such a connector starts up, it can look in the external system to find out the offset that was last written, and can then tell Kafka Connect where it wants to start reading. With this approach your connector may be able to do *exactly once* processing of messages.

When sink connectors do this, they actually don't need Kafka Connect to commit any offsets at all. The `flush` method is simply an opportunity for your connector to know which offsets that Kafka Connect is committing for you, and since it doesn't return anything it can't modify those offsets or tell Kafka Connect which offsets the connector is handling.

This is where the `preCommit` method comes in. It really is a replacement for `flush` (it actually takes the same parameters as `flush`), except that it is expected to return the offsets that Kafka Connect should commit. By default, `preCommit` just calls `flush` and then returns the same offsets that were passed to `preCommit`, which means Kafka Connect should commit all the offsets it passed to the connector via `preCommit`. But if your `preCommit` returns an empty set of offsets, then Kafka Connect will record no offsets at all.

So, if your connector is going to handle all offsets in the external system and doesn't need Kafka Connect to record anything, then you should override the `preCommit` method instead of `flush`, and return an empty set of offsets.

Comment: Is this the same for "List<SourceRecord> poll()" method in the Source Connectors?  Kafka Connect doesn't flush the offSet right after it writes the List of SourceRecords to the target topic ?